# Send Non-Json Request with Python

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I would like to send python post request with non-json request body. It seems python "requests" package send a request body only in json format. Is there a way send a non-json request body with pyhon "requests" or other package?

Comment: What are you trying to send, and how are you trying to send it?

Comment: Maybe [this helps](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Comment: Example request that I would like to send is: "POST /api-endpoint username=x&password=y". Data in request body (username and password) are not in json format. Thus, I could not send request via python "requests" package.